# Options to get the class properties in a name value dictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using .NET 4.6:

I am looking for options to get a name value collection dictionary of the properties in a given class. An obvious option is reflection. However, back in .NET 2.0 days the use of refelection was considered heavy on performance and it was not recommended.

What are the better options that we have in.NET 4.6?

Is there any feature in Entity Framework that makes it easier to implement this requirement?

**Update 1**

I am building a MailMerge style template system and I am replacing tags like  {PropertyName} with the value of the Property.

Some of the data are coming from the EF entity classes and some come from POCO classed.

Comment: This is much closer to how queries work in standard ADO.net.  Do you need to use an ORM like Entity Framework?  Because it seems like you are trying to work around the existence of EF when it would be easier to avoid it in the first place.

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you need to get a list of properties at runtime, that is what reflection *is*. If you can generate the list at compile-time, then that would be faster. But really, using reflection isn't that much of a big performance problem - not that you've defined your performance constraints, so who knows if it's fast "enough"..

Comment: @SamAxe@recursive : I am adding more clarification to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one way or another you're going to be using reflection.

I'd suggest caching the structure of your model types when the template system loads.  That will speed up the template processing.  But honestly, unless you are processing hundreds of thousands of templates at a time, you're probably not going to gain a significant speed increase from caching (you should test though).

Another option, which I've used and highly recommend, is RazorEngine.  It's a template engine that's already built, based on ASP.NET's razor template engine.

Comment: Thank you for help. Are you referring to https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine ? Did you find it stable enough to be used in a mission critical windows service application with large volume of data being rendered?

Comment: I can not make any recommendations.  Simply giving you options.  You'll have to make your own determination as to suitability for your project.